# Relay that detects 240VAC and switches 12V DC

Tags: voltage, current, relay, ac-dc, sensing

I'm wishing to detect the loss of AC power (in this case 240V) and when this event occurs have a 12V DC circuit go to earth. This will trigger an alarm for users to react to situation.

Can anyone recommend anything? Voltage sensing relay?

I have a current sensing clip-on transformer, I bought via eBay, but it only provides 3 volts 
AC which seems too low for AC/DC relays I have found on Google and Alibaba.

Answer (score 3):

Any standard relay with a 240 V coil would serve.

Comment: Any standard relay with a 240 VAC coil and a N.C. (normally closed) contact pair would serve.